# Perform activity on each module install or upgrade

Tags: module, installation, odoo, upgrade, openerp-7

whenever user install or upgrade any module I need to perform particular action based on that.

I looked into module.py for methods button_install, button_upgrade etc and tried to override it but models for specific modules are not created yet. Plus if i am installing module via terminal button_upgrade and button_install doesn't get called.

Which method should i use to perform above activity?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run some code for any module install/upgrade, create a module that has a model that inherits from ir.module.module and override the button_install and button_upgrade methods.

If you want to run some code for a specific module there are two options:

In one of your models override init (not **init**) or weird stuff will happen.  Have a look at account_analytic_entries_report.py in core account module for an example.

Create a my_module_config.xml file, add in a entry like this:

```
<function model="my.model.name" name="do_stuff" />
```

Comment: Hello Adrian, Thanks for quick reply. I did override the button_install and button_upgrade methods but as i mentioned in my question while i am installing module via terminal using -i inherited method doesn't get called. Any suggestion? Regards,

Comment: I don't know for v7, but for v6, the installion/update of a module with the terminal use the 'button_install' and 'button_upgrade' methods.